# How to run a PHPUnit test in Windows?

Tags: php, phpunit

So I have manually installed PHPUnit by downloading the files from pear.phpunit.de and extracting them to C:\PHP\PEAR folder. I have the PEAR folder in include path. How can I run this test?

```
class StackTest extends  PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testEmpty()
    {
        $stack = array();
        $this->assertEmpty($stack);

        return $stack;
    }

    /**
     * @depends testEmpty
     */
    public function testPush(array $stack)
    {
        array_push($stack, 'foo');
        $this->assertEquals('foo', $stack[count($stack)-1]);
        $this->assertNotEmpty($stack);

        return $stack;
    }

    /**
     * @depends testPush
     */
    public function testPop(array $stack)
    {
        $this->assertEquals('foo', array_pop($stack));
        $this->assertEmpty($stack);
    }
}
```

There is no executable command line tool in the PHPUnit directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my machine, `phpunit.bat` was added in my main php install directory. I run tests by calling

```
phpunit NameOfMyTestWithoutPhpExtension
```

in the directory containing the test.

The batch file simply invokes main php interpreter passing `phpunit` as the source file and appending other arguments to its invocation. If you don't have the batch file, try running

```
php "c:\PHP\PEAR\phpunit.php" NameOfMyTestWithoutPhpExtension
```

Comment: It's a PHP file. There is no *.exe file, only a *.bat which passes phpunit to php.exe

Comment: Ok, this works: php "c:\PHP\PEAR\phpunit.php" NameOfMyTestWithoutPhpExtension